# Flask-RESTX - Arabic text in response body

Tags: flask, utf-8, flask-restx

I'm running a rest api with swagger, flask-restx

However, my problem is that in the swagger UI (http://127.0.0.1:5000/ ?) when testing out the endpoint, arabic text in the response body is returned as excaped characters `\\u0645\\u0635\\u0646\\u0648\\u0639 \\u0645\`
Same problem when using postman

The problem does not occur when using sublime text request package or when simply entering the URL in the browser (I have a jsonify extension)

Here is a shortened version of my code

```
@app.route('/products')
def products():
  # logic with database

  return JSONEncoder().encode(products)

name_space = api.namespace('product', description='Product API')
@name_space.route("/")
class ProductClass(Resource):
  def get(self):
    return make_response(products())
```

When I call the endpoint `products` it works fine, but when I call `product` it does not.

Answer (score 0):

Define the following function in Python:

```
def inverse_repr(a_string):
    a_string = repr(a_string)
    a_string = a_string.replace('\\\\','\\')
    # encode/decode stuff
    return a_string.strip("'").encode().decode("unicode-escape")
```

Sample usage:

```
print( inverse_repr('\\u0645\\u0635\\u0646\\u0648\\u0639 \\u0645') )
print( inverse_repr('\\x43\\x69\\x74\\x72\\x6f\\xeb\\x6e') )
print( inverse_repr('d\\xE9j\\xE0 vu') )
print( inverse_repr('\\U0001F5B6 Printer Icon') )
```

Result:

```
مصنوع م
Citroën
déjà vu
 Printer Icon
```